# Is there a Microsoft SQL Server binding?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vala, vapi

Could someone give me an orientation on the use of any version of SQL Server?

I'm working with version 2003 at the moment.

Comment: There's no SQL Server 2003... there's 2000, 2005, 2008... but no 2003.

Comment: This is not the place to ask general questions on how to use programming languages.  This is a place for specific issue-related questions and answers.

Comment: @JNK While I agree that SO is not about asking for library in general, this is a very specific case. There are only a handful of possibilities here. This won't lead to a primarily opionion based discussion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a C library [freetds](http://www.freetds.org/) that allows you to natively talk to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases.

In order to  use it in vala you need to [create](https://wiki.gnome.org/Vala/Bindings) a "vapi file" (probably writing it manually) containing the class and method declarations in Vala syntax

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the freetds library that o3o mentioned you can use unixODBC to access Microsoft SQL Server.

There are multiple unixODBC drivers for Microsoft SQL Server:

- [Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on Linux](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451.aspx) (There is also an older version available
- [Microsoft SQL Server driver from easysoft](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/index.html)
- [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/)

There is also a list of unixODBC drviers on [their homepage](http://www.unixodbc.org/).

There is no readily available `vapi` file for unixODBC at the time of this writing. I'm working on a [two layered approach for this](https://github.com/antiochus/unixodbc-vala). It's not finished yet, but might be useful someday ;).